# Get source of audio recording

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for some help. I have a winform app which has to record a audio and save the recording locally on the disk.

I am sorry I don't know the terminologies used, but does windows form or perhaps c# allow to record audio file from different sources? Like is there a way to find out from where the audio is being recorded. Either it is from a microphone or can user record it without using microphone too (from speakers)? And what is recording from soundcard? It is same as recording without using microphone?

What are the ways a audio can be recorded? I know it can be from microphone but can we record from a speaker?

Comment: While in theory you can use _electrically_ use a speaker as a microphone, it's not possible to use a computer's speaker because it's wired up to an amplifier (and not a DAC, as an analog input would be) so it's not possible to use it for input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on CodeProject [CLICK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31356/C-MP-Sound-Capturing-Recording-Component) which contains an example of sound recorder control with source selection.

[image: sond recorder]

Comment: By source selection you mean microphone or speaker?